# Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, keypress

I've read all the answers on to this questions and none of the solutions seem to work.

Also, I am getting the vibe that triggering keypress with special characters does not work at all. Can someone verify who has done this?

Comment: No you miss understood the concept. This is not how is it supposed to work. trigger will only call the event handler. It will not actually print the key. If you want to simulate the effect of printing the key, then just add the key to the input value and trigger the event at the same time.

Comment: Interesting, i didnt know that. In that case, can you tell me if triggering the event will also trigger it for non-jquery libs. for example if i have a onKeydown set up in plain JS, will it capture my "fake" event?

Comment: yes, if there was an onkeydown='...' set up in plain js. It will be triggered by the fake event. I wasn't sure about it. But I made a quick test and it worked.

Comment: @Nadia Thanks for that! I've read over all the answers wondering why things weren't working before realizing my expectations weren't correct. I suspect a lot of other people will have the same misconceptions.

Comment: Two years later... reading the page it seem that the definitive way is :
$('input#search').trigger($.Event( 'keydown', {which:$.ui.keyCode.ENTER, keyCode:$.ui.keyCode.ENTER}));

Answer (score 385, accepted):

If you want to trigger the keypress or keydown event then all you have to do is:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 50; // # Some key code value
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Comment: I added an example for triggering the event

Comment: Very nice answer. Worth noting that jQuery.Event is available for jQuery 1.3 or greater. It became relevant in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823617/how-do-i-have-jquerys-autocomplete-plugin-display-its-dropdown-list-upon-page-lo/1823732

Comment: This did not work for me with a jQuery UI slider. I had to set e.keyCode like OreiA's answer below.

Comment: fwiw, I had more success with 'keyup' for my application

Comment: I had to do `e.keyCode = 32;`

Comment: The question I have is if I'm using Japanese input with Katakana keyboard I am seeing an incoming keydown event of 229. If I attempt to trigger a keypress in the input field using the key code of 229 nothing shows up in the input field. Is there a way to trigger international characters?

Comment: can we changed jQuery with $ character?

Answer (score 85):

Slightly more concise now [with jQuery 1.6+](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/):

```
var e = jQuery.Event( 'keydown', { which: $.ui.keyCode.ENTER } );

$('input').trigger(e);
```

(If you're not using jQuery UI, sub in the appropriate keycode instead.)

Comment: Just remember to substitute 'keyCode' for 'which' as well.

Comment: Yes you must define which and keyCode to be safe (if the event listener checks for e.keyCode, it will only work if you define keyCode when creating the jQuery.Event object)

Comment: jQuery normalises which/keyCode so putting either in should do both.

Comment: +1 for the link to api.jquery.com; and current jQuery versions don't normalize which/keyCode, so you should supply both for safety

Comment: @Victor, current jQuery versions do exactly that: "The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode". You comment is a year old so maybe this has changed since then, but now no one will be confused by this.

Comment: @SamuelLindblom I should've written it more clear: jQuery don't normalize event properties passed via `.trigger(jQuery.Event('name', props))`. Look at example http://jsfiddle.net/9ggmrbpd/1/ - properties of triggered event are passed as is. Source code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L739

Answer (score 73):

The real answer has to include keyCode:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 50; // # Some key code value
e.keyCode = 50
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Even though jQuery's website says that which and keyCode are normalized they are very badly mistaken. It's always safest to do the standard cross-browser checks for e.which and e.keyCode and in this case just define both.

Comment: +1. By the way, `e.keyCode = e.which = 50;` in a single line would be nicer. :)

Comment: I just found out that using only `keyCode` didn't work. Had to set both to make it work

Comment: @Sk8erPeter it won't unless it's a golph coding competition

Answer (score 19):

If you're using jQuery UI too, you can do like this:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Comment: e.which does not seem to work with my jQuery UI slider. Thanks for this answer. It does work.

Answer (score 7):

I made it work with keyup.

```
$("#id input").trigger('keyup');
```

Comment: in my question 6 years ago, I also wanted to set the keycode, but didnt know how.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, for me that work with this...

```
var e2key = function(e) {
    if (!e) return '';
    var event2key = {
        '96':'0', '97':'1', '98':'2', '99':'3', '100':'4', '101':'5', '102':'6', '103':'7', '104':'8', '105':'9', // Chiffres clavier num
        '48':'m0', '49':'m1', '50':'m2', '51':'m3', '52':'m4', '53':'m5', '54':'m6', '55':'m7', '56':'m8', '57':'m9', // Chiffres caracteres speciaux
        '65':'a', '66':'b', '67':'c', '68':'d', '69':'e', '70':'f', '71':'g', '72':'h', '73':'i', '74':'j', '75':'k', '76':'l', '77':'m', '78':'n', '79':'o', '80':'p', '81':'q', '82':'r', '83':'s', '84':'t', '85':'u', '86':'v', '87':'w', '88':'x', '89':'y', '90':'z', // Alphabet
        '37':'left', '39':'right', '38':'up', '40':'down', '13':'enter', '27':'esc', '32':'space', '107':'+', '109':'-', '33':'pageUp', '34':'pageDown' // KEYCODES
    };
    return event2key[(e.which || e.keyCode)];
};

var page5Key = function(e, customKey) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault();
    switch(e2key(customKey || e)) {
        case 'left': /*...*/ break;
        case 'right': /*...*/ break;
    }
};

$(document).bind('keyup', page5Key);

$(document).trigger('keyup', [{preventDefault:function(){},keyCode:37}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Of you want to do it in a single line you can use

```
$("input").trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', { which: '1'.charCodeAt(0) }));
```

Answer (score 2):

`console.log( String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) );`

no need to map character i guess.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to take into account the current cursor and text selection...

This wasn't working for me for an AngularJS app on Chrome. As Nadia points out in the original comments, the character is never visible in the input field (at least, that was my experience). In addition, the previous solutions don't take into account the current text selection in the input field. I had to use a wonderful library [jquery-selection](http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/).

I have a custom on-screen numeric keypad that fills in multiple input fields. I had to...

1. On focus, save the lastFocus.element
2. On blur, save the current text selection (start and stop)

   ```
   var pos = element.selection('getPos')
   lastFocus.pos = { start: pos.start, end: pos.end}
   ```
3. When a button on the my keypad is pressed:

   ```
   lastFocus.element.selection( 'setPos', lastFocus.pos)
   lastFocus.element.selection( 'replace', {text: myKeyPadChar, caret: 'end'})
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It can be accomplished like this [docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-eventType-extraParameters)

```
$('input').trigger("keydown", {which: 50});
```

Comment: This does not seem to work because this uses the extraParameters argument which does not set anything inside the event argument but adds extra arguments to the event handler callback.

Comment: Not a valid solution