# How do I have jQuery's autocomplete plugin display its dropdown list upon page load?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

http://community.sciencecareers.org/mt-static/plugins/CommunityPlus/js/autocomplete/
http://community.sciencecareers.org/mt-static/plugins/CommunityPlus/js/autocomplete/demo/

Trying to programmatically trigger the display of the autocompletion list results.  This, instead of waiting for user input.

Is this doable?  (I've tried getting the element's focus, calling a Javascript down-arrow key event.  No dice)

Comment: Erm, why do you want it this way? So users can see the list to decide what to select before typing anything?

Comment: jquery ui has a specific meaning -- http://jqueryui.com/ -- , I think that tag could be removed.

Comment: o.k.w:  yes, re: "So users can see the list to decide what to select before typing anything?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If, and only if, you are using a version of jQuery 1.3 or greater, you can create a [`jQuery.Event`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event) object, then `trigger()` it. I was only able to get it to work if the element is also focused. So this code works for the "**E-Mail (local):**" example on [the demo page](http://community.sciencecareers.org/mt-static/plugins/CommunityPlus/js/autocomplete/demo/).

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 40;
$('#suggest13').trigger('focus').attr('value',' ').trigger(e);
```

I'm not sure exactly what your situation is, I think it's somewhat dependent on the autocomplete actually showing something if only a space is pressed. That's not always the case.

Comment: Yeah, I had already come across that.  Thanks all the same!  Unfortunately I'm stuck with jQuery 1.2.6 for the time being.

Comment: which = 13 or keyCode = 13 is same as enter key for this kind of usage right?

Answer (score 6):

and what about this? `$("#autocompleteid").autocomplete("search")`

Comment: Calling `search` seems for me to result in an autocomplete dropdown which does not close upon selecting a value.

Comment: It's based on events here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#events. I don't know if that your behavior is caused by my code or your code, in every way take a look at the link. I think you can combine select and close functions.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#mainCombo_input").trigger('keydown.autocomplete');  will open the autocomplete div   and also to display the dropdown.
```

And you can also use

```
$("#mainCombo_input").val("Item1");    
$("#mainCombo_input").trigger('keydown.autocomplete'); to open div with on
```

Comment: This seemed to only work the first time the button was clicked.

Comment: The first option here, triggering `keydown.autocomplete` worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Per  [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search), you can trigger a search (also mentioned in other answer). Since your case is on page load and it might not have any data on the input field you'll need to change minLength before an empty search can be ran:

```
$yourInputField.autocomplete('option', 'minLength', 0);
$yourInputField.autocomplete('search', "");
```