# Firing a keyboard event on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit

I'm trying to fire a keyboard event to a page using javascript on Chrome.
I had an approach that used to work on Firefox:

```
pressKey = function(key, shift) {
  var evt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
  evt.initKeyEvent("keypress", false, true, null, false, false,
                   shift, false, keyCode(key), key.charCodeAt(0));
  document.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

where key is the desired key and keyCode changes lowercase letters into highercase and also calls charCodeAt().

My problem is that events on Safari/Chrome don't have initKeyEvent, but initKeyboardEvent. The main difference I could notice was that you have to pass the key as a keyIdentifier (which looks like a unicode character) instead of passing the keycode and the keychar. Nonetheless I still can't manage to make it work.

I've also tried the JQuery approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery/832121#832121) without success.

**EDIT:**
I debugged this a little further and it seems that the event on Chrome does trigger the listeners, but keyCode/charCode is always 0. I've tried to set evt.keyCode or evt.charCode with no success either.

Comment: I've removed a comment from the question and put as answer, because I think that even thought it doesn't really solve the question, it might be really helpful for people having the same problem as I did.

Comment: Hey how did you solve the problem? I am also facing issue of simulating key-press of left and right on chrome/safari. But no success, how did you do it?

Comment: Did you try the solution I posted?  It worked for me and would probably have helped you achieve your goal, so it's odd to me that you accepted your own answer of "it's a bug".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just want to throw this basic snippet out there. It works in Chrome and is based on the hack mentioned  by Paul Irish.
It uses charCode instead of keyCode (which can be useful in certain situation), but adapt to keyCode if you so please.

```
var keyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {bubbles:true}); 
Object.defineProperty(keyboardEvent, 'charCode', {get:function(){return this.charCodeVal;}}); 
keyboardEvent.charCodeVal = [your char code];
document.body.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
```

Answer (score 22):

I've tracked this down to a [bug on Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16735) where created events only contain KeyIdentifier but no keyCode/charCode as can be seen on the [browser source code](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/dom/KeyboardEvent.cpp). There seems to be a patch going on to solve this. So I guess this is not a proper question anymore...

Comment: People have reported success with this beautiful hack here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10520017/89484

Comment: Two things happened since: 1. Last year I joined the Chrome team and assigned this bug to myself; 2. I gave up fixing this, since it seems the new standards deprecate this functionality (and it's deceively hard to fix this bug on all platforms).

Answer (score 11):

If you want do it in the right way, you can use DOM *Keyboard Event Level 4* KeyboardEvent construct and **key** property.

In latest browsers or with [DOM Keyboard Event Level 3/4 polyfill](https://github.com/termi/DOM-Keyboard-Event-Level-3-polyfill) you can do something like this:

```
element.addEventListener(function(e){ console.log(e.key, e.char, e.keyCode) })

var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {bubbles : true, cancelable : true, key : "Q", char : "Q", shiftKey : true});
element.dispatchEvent(e);

//If you need legacy property "keyCode".
// Note: In some browsers you can't overwrite "keyCode" property. (At least in Safari)
delete e.keyCode;
Object.defineProperty(e, "keyCode", {"value" : 666})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/termi/yjc5F/)

["map event.key to character values of a normal QUERTY (en-US) layout" proposal demo](http://h123.ru/-/tests/KeyboardEvent/)

Note that **keyCode** and **charCode** are deprecated in latest Spec (www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/). So the is no chance to Chrome to implement *initKeyEvent* with **keyCode** support. But you can always override this value:
**UPDATE**: bad method:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
evt.initKeyEvent("keypress", false, true, null, false, false,
               shift, false, keyCode(key), key.charCodeAt(0));
if(evt.keyCode != keyCode(key)) {
    delete evt.keyCode;
    // Note: In some browsers you can't overwrite "keyCode" property. (At least in Safari)
    Object.defineProperty(evt, "keyCode", { keyCode(key) });
}
```

Or you can **update** event prototype: **UPDATE**: bad method:

```
// Note: In some browsers you can't overwrite "keyCode" property. (At least in Safari)
var _native_keyCode_getter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(KeyboardEvent.prototype, "keyCode");
Object.defineProperty(KeyboardEvent.prototype, "keyCode", {
    "enumerable" : true,
    "configurable" : true,
    "get" : function() {
        if("__keyCode" in this)return this["__keyCode"];

        return _native_keyCode_getter.call(this);
    },
    "set" : function(newValue) {
        return this["__keyCode"] = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : newValue;
    }
});
```

**Update**
There are various implementation of initKeyboardEvent. In my KeyboardEvent polyfill I detect it somehow like this ([gist](https://gist.github.com/4654819)):

```
var _initKeyboardEvent_type = (function( e ) {
    try {
        e.initKeyboardEvent(
            "keyup" // in DOMString typeArg
            , false // in boolean canBubbleArg
            , false // in boolean cancelableArg
            , global // in views::AbstractView viewArg
            , "+" // [test]in DOMString keyIdentifierArg | webkit event.keyIdentifier | IE9 event.key
            , 3 // [test]in unsigned long keyLocationArg | webkit event.keyIdentifier | IE9 event.location
            , true // [test]in boolean ctrlKeyArg | webkit event.shiftKey | old webkit event.ctrlKey | IE9 event.modifiersList
            , false // [test]shift | alt
            , true // [test]shift | alt
            , false // meta
            , false // altGraphKey
        );
        return ((e["keyIdentifier"] || e["key"]) == "+" && (e["keyLocation"] || e["location"]) == 3) && (
            e.ctrlKey ?
                e.altKey ? // webkit
                    1
                    :
                    3
                :
                e.shiftKey ?
                    2 // webkit
                    :
                    4 // IE9
            ) || 9 // FireFox|w3c
            ;
    }
    catch ( __e__ ) { alert("browser do not support KeyboardEvent") }
})( document.createEvent( "KeyboardEvent" ) );

var e = document.createEvent( "KeyboardEvent" );
...
if( "initKeyEvent" in e ) {//FF
    //https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initKeyEvent
    e.initKeyEvent( type, _bubbles, _cancelable, _view, _ctrlKey, _altKey, _shiftKey, _metaKey, _keyCode, _keyCode );
}
else if( "initKeyboardEvent" in e ) {//https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent#initKeyboardEvent()
    if( _try_initKeyboardEvent ) {
        if( _initKeyboardEvent_type == 1 ) { // webkit
            //http://stackoverflow.com/a/8490774/1437207
            //https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13368
            e.initKeyboardEvent( type, _bubbles, _cancelable, _view, _key, _location, _ctrlKey, _shiftKey, _altKey, _metaKey, _altGraphKey );
        }
        else if( _initKeyboardEvent_type == 2 ) { // old webkit
            //http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=52408
            e.initKeyboardEvent( type, _bubbles, _cancelable, _view, _ctrlKey, _altKey, _shiftKey, _metaKey, _keyCode, _keyCode );
        }
        else if( _initKeyboardEvent_type == 3 ) { // webkit
            e.initKeyboardEvent( type, _bubbles, _cancelable, _view, _key, _location, _ctrlKey, _altKey, _shiftKey, _metaKey, _altGraphKey );
        }
        else if( _initKeyboardEvent_type == 4 ) { // IE9
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975297(v=vs.85).aspx
            e.initKeyboardEvent( type, _bubbles, _cancelable, _view, _key, _location, _modifiersListArg, _repeat, _locale );
        }
        else { // FireFox|w3c
            //http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-KeyboardEvent-initKeyboardEvent
            //https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent#initKeyboardEvent()
            e.initKeyboardEvent( type, _bubbles, _cancelable, _view, _char, _key, _location, _modifiersListArg, _repeat, _locale );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither of your suggested workarounds work. The first fails because the `keyCode` property is not configurable. The second because the property descriptor's `get` is never actually called.

Comment: "The first fails because the keyCode property is not configurable."
I am update my polyfill to fix various bugs and browser compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, a TextEvent might work. (It worked for me for my needs - for chrome. This is not cross-browser tested, but then, the question was specifically about chrome.)

```
// get a reference to the DOM element you want to affect
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
// create a TextEvent
var textEvent = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
// initialize the TextEvent
textEvent.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, null, String.fromCharCode(13)+"\r\n", 9, "en-US");
// dispatch ('fire') the TextEvent
input.dispatchEvent(textEvent);
```

Comment: Although this triggers the event, it doesn't actually insert the text.  Security "feature" in Chrome 61?  - try this, it doesn't work https://gist.github.com/flying19880517/3180456

Answer (score 2):

You can work around the Webkit bug using `createEvent('Event')` rather than `createEvent('KeyboardEvent')`, and then assigning the `keyCode` property. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12522752/52207) and [this example](http://jsbin.com/awenaq/3).

Comment: There is one difference between the two. If you use createEvent("Events") in WebKit and send an event with keyCode 13 to a form element, it doesn't actually mimic the return key. If there's a listener listening for keyCode 13, it will trigger that, but compare to Firefox where it does actually  mimic the pressing of the return key on the keyboard and submits the form. Been dealing with just this issue for a day or so and thought I'd share. :)