# DropDownList and UpdatePanel - changing selection with keyboard do not cause postback

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

I have and UpdatePanel with DropDownList. DropDownList control is set as a trigger for UpdatePanel.

Everything works fine when I change DropDownList selection with mouse. But when I do it with keyboard (like up/down key) request is not issued. How can I address it?

Thanks,Pawel

Comment: press enter after changing a value .

Comment: You can do it using javascript.
Check this link--

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922879/firing-down-arrow-key-press-in-a-select-box-via-javascript