# Hotkey to Button

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to make a keyboard shortcut that will click on a button on a webpage. 
Like I would like to have a hotkey : Ctrl+S to automatically click on Search on Google.

I've tried this : Shortcut Manager plugin but I'm not sure how to assign it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

<kbd>[**See this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TQAm9/)</kbd>

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    var rr = $('#report').html();
    $('#report').html(rr + '<br />' + keycode);

    if (e.ctrlKey) alert('Control pressed');
    //if (!(keycode == 115 && e.ctrlKey) && !(keycode == 19)) return true;
    if (!(keycode == 83 && e.ctrlKey) && !(keycode == 17)) return true;
    alert("Ctrl-S pressed");
    $('#gsearch').trigger('click'); //or just .click() also works
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Note that webkit browsers will not trap ctrl, alt, shift, etc keys. [See this article for info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942678/keyboardevent-in-chrome-keycode-is-0#answer-12522752)