# Triggering Google-Reader's refresh in Chrome (Works in Firefox)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, userscripts, google-reader

I have a userscript for *Google Reader*, and as part of that userscript I need to trigger a refresh, which I do in Firefox by simulating a `keypress` for the letter <kbd>r</kbd>.

```
function simulateRefresh()
{
    var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    e.initKeyEvent('keypress', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 82, 82);
    document.body.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

This works in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Apparently `initKeyEvent` is not supported, and I'm supposed to use `initKeyboardEvent`.
So far I've had zero luck with this (There is no error in the console, but the refresh does not fire.)  I am using jQuery if that matters.

I also tried triggering `click` on the refresh button, but this failed in both browsers (not sure why, the click event is firing according to the Chrome debugger, but the code is obfuscated, so I can't figure it out).

Comment: Couldn't you just ask the browser to do a refresh? I don't understand the need to fake a keypress. what about the options given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript

Comment: Well I don't wanna refresh the whole webapp, just have it refetch the result for a specific feed (Starred Items in this case). Refreshing the whole thing is a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google webapps often do not use a simple `keypress` or `click`, when a complex sequence of states will do. ;-)

So sending a "click" to the refresh button does not work, but sending an "over, down, up" triad does.  Like so:

```js
var refreshBtn = document.querySelector ('#viewer-refresh');

//--- Click by itself does not work!
triggerMouseEvent (refreshBtn, 'mouseover');
triggerMouseEvent (refreshBtn, 'mousedown');
triggerMouseEvent (refreshBtn, 'mouseup');

function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

---

---

A similar kind of state-sequence may be required for the keyboard shortcut. (Testing continues.)

**Update:**  For the keyboard events, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1897491/331508) which mentions [Webkit Bug 16735: "Keyboard events created with DOM have keyCode and charCode of 0"](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16735) -- which is still open after 4.5 years(!!) and *might* apply here.

Comment: Works like a charm =c) Thanks. I'm off to integrate the code. Now that i can click on stuff this might end up being an even better solution then the keyboard events.

Comment: A workaround solution for the mentioned webkit keyboard event bug is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key/10520017#10520017

Answer (score 0):

Tried `$('#refreshButton').trigger('click');` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to check whether the `initKeyboardEvent` method is implemented or not.

```
var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvents');
(e.initKeyboardEvent || e.initKeyEvent).call(e, 'keypress', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 82, 82);
document.body.dispatchEvent(e);
```

This works for me in Chrome.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried when I figured out it's initKeyboardEvent in Chrome, but it's not working for me. Same thing doesn't error, but doesn't work. I have Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79 m, don't know if this makes a difference.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle for us to try?

Comment: The issue is probably not in Chrome, but with Google reader.  Google webapps are notorious for this kind of thing.

Comment: Brock's right. Just some Google silliness. I ended up using his mouse event solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to dispatch the event from your content script, unfortunately that does not work. [You need to inject the code into the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/612202):

```
function injectJavaScript(textContent) {
  var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
  scriptElement.textContent = textContent;

  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptElement);
}

var code = '(' + function() {
  var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvents');
  e.initKeyboardEvent('keypress', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 82, 82);
  document.body.dispatchEvent(e);
} + ')();';

injectJavaScript(code);
```

Comment: I don't know what this ominous Google Reader is, but I thought it was a more common problem.

Comment: The title seems generic, but the Q text makes clear that the problem is specific to *Google Reader*.  Your answer would work on a sensibly coded site, but not on *Google Reader*.

Comment: Thanks Dan, but this solution doesn't work. I'm gonna end up using the mouse solution from Brock.  That being said, i might also test sending keydown/keypress/keyup combo as well, and see if it's the same pattern.

Comment: I've tried various KB combos... So far with no luck on Google reader.  Next step (for me) is to see if it's that Chrome bug in play.  Issue back-burnered, for now.