# Chrome extension - generate keypress

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-events

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that generates simulated keyboard events.

[This question explains how to generate the keyboard event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987380/how-to-to-initialize-keyboard-event-with-given-char-keycode-in-a-chrome-extensio), but when I run it on my content script it generates the following error:

```
error: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
```

What do I do to fix this?

Here's my manifest.xml

```
{
  "name": "2048 forever",
  "description": "SOLVES EVERYTHING",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["keyboard.js"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Solve the things"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js contains:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');

    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
    });

    triggerKeyEvent(document.body, 38);
});


function triggerKeyEvent(element, charCode) {
    // We cannot pass object references, so generate an unique selector
    var attribute = 'robw_' + Date.now();
    element.setAttribute(attribute, '');
    var selector = element.tagName + '[' + attribute + ']';

    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.textContent = '(' + function(charCode, attribute, selector) {
        // Get reference to element...
        var element = document.querySelector(selector);
        element.removeAttribute(attribute);

        // Create KeyboardEvent instance
        var event = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvents');
        event.initKeyboardEvent(
            /* type         */ 'keydown',
            /* bubbles      */ true,
            /* cancelable   */ false,
            /* view         */ window,
            /* keyIdentifier*/ '',
            /* keyLocation  */ 0,
            /* ctrlKey      */ false,
            /* altKey       */ false,
            /* shiftKey     */ false,
            /* metaKey      */ false,
            /* altGraphKey  */ false
        );
        // Define custom values
        // This part requires the script to be run in the page's context
        var getterCode = {get: function() {return charCode}};
        var getterChar = {get: function() {return String.fromCharCode(charCode)}};
        Object.defineProperties(event, {
            charCode: getterCode,
            which: getterChar,
            keyCode: getterCode, // Not fully correct
            key: getterChar,     // Not fully correct
            char: getterChar
        });

        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    } + ')(' + charCode + ', "' + attribute + '", "' + selector + '")';

    console.log('text content: ' + s.textContent);

    (document.head||doc.documentElement).appendChild(s);
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `manifest.json`

Comment: Yup, just added it. I have tried injecting the script as a second file but I then don't have access to document.

Comment: `manifest.xml`? That might be the reason it is not working!

Comment: Where is your code? In `background.js`? How is this a content script?

Comment: The reason you are getting this particular error message is because the linked answer creates a `<script>` element with inline JavaScript inside it and attaches that to the dom.

Comment: I don't know if it's a content script, actually. This is my first extension. I put the code in background.js.

Comment: The other problem is that the script is injected into the background, which isn't the desired outcome.