# Manually trigger / simulate hotkeys (keydown, keypress, keyup) with injected Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to build a chrome extension to automate tasks through custom hotkeys in Gmail.

To avoid messing with the DOM, I'm working with the existing hotkeys that Gmail provides.

An example of what I want to achieve: I want Ctrl+Shift+T to trigger the combination of 'l' 't' 'return' and 'e' hotkeys, which will mean that the email is labelled 't' and archived.

I'm starting with the most 'basic' trigger:

- In gmail, if you type 'c', it brings the compose window. With *monitorEvents*, you can see the keydown, keypress, keyup events triggered.
- I've tried many different approaches ([jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery), [JS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key), [chrome debugger API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987380/how-to-to-initialize-keyboard-event-with-given-char-keycode-in-a-chrome-extensio/34722970#34722970)... ) but I'm not able to trigger the event. I get no error.
- I've also tried other websites like github.com and 's' to trigger search and no result either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Github's js code checks `event.target` in its `keydown` handler, which can't be spoofed. I guess gmail does the same, so you're out of luck.

Comment: Depending on the element you trigger from, you set the target, right? `document.querySelector("body.logged-in.env-production.macintosh.page-dashboard").dispatchEvent(a);` sets the target correctly

Comment: Set breakpoints inside the site's js code, dispatch an event from a console and see what happens, why it's rejected.