# Sending keyboard events programmatically doesn't dispatch them into inputs

Tags: javascript, input, keyboard-events

I am sending programmatically generated keyboard events to the document. I was hoping that the currently focused input element would display them, however it doesn't. The events are generated from a string with this function:

```
const simulateKeyPress = keys => {
  keys.split('').forEach(theKey => {
    const e = new window.KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
      bubbles: true,
      key: theKey,
      keyCode: theKey.charCodeAt(0),
      charCode: theKey.charCodeAt(0),
    })
    document.dispatchEvent(e)
  })
}
```

If I add an EventListener to the document it'll receive all the events. Their `isTrusted` flag is set to false however, might this be the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It cannot be done from website programmatically. Like you said `isTrusted` boolean as false will not trigger the keypress correctly (since Chrome 53): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

I tried to solve this in here: https://codepen.io/zvona/pen/LjNEyr?editors=1010

where practically only difference is to dispatch the event for `activeElement`, like: `document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(e);`. In addition, if you're able to hook on input's events, you can add event listener to do the job:

```
input.addEventListener('keypress', (evt) => {
  evt.target.value += evt.key;
});
```

But like mentioned, it's not trusted event. However, this can be done via browser extensions (see: [How to to initialize keyboard event with given char/keycode in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987380/how-to-to-initialize-keyboard-event-with-given-char-keycode-in-a-chrome-extensio))

Comment: Hi, do you by chance have some reference on the "will not trigger the keypress correctly (since Chrome 53)". Is there any statement? Is supporting the `isTrusted` property really means that?