# Triggering a keydown event programmatically in vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, keydown

I have an event attached to the window running on `keydown`. I would like to test this by having a routine (per interval) programmatically hitting a key on the keyboard. The following code doesn't work - but works fine if I'm actually pressing a key on the keyboard.

I originally tried:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent"); 
setInterval(function() {
    evt.initKeyEvent("keydown", true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 13, 13);
}, 500);
```

Here's my current `keydown` event:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(k) {
    switch(k.keyCode) {
        case 38: //up
            if (Game.Area[Game.Player.x][Game.Player.y-1].type !== 0 && Game.Player.y > 0) {
                Game.Player.y--;
            }
            Game.Player.d = 0;
            break;
        case 40: //down
            if (Game.Area[Game.Player.x][Game.Player.y+1].type !== 0 && Game.Player.y < Game.Area[0].length-1) {
                Game.Player.y++;
            }
            Game.Player.d = 1;
            break;
        case 37: //left
            if (Game.Area[Game.Player.x-1][Game.Player.y].type !== 0 && Game.Player.x > 0) {
                Game.Player.x--;
            }
            Game.Player.d = 2;
            break;
        case 39: //right
            if (Game.Area[Game.Player.x+1][Game.Player.y].type !== 0 && Game.Player.y < Game.Area.length-1) {
                Game.Player.x++;
            }
            Game.Player.d = 3;
            break;
        case 66:
            if (Game.Player.d === 0 && Game.Player.y > 0) { //up
                Game.Area[Game.Player.x][Game.Player.y-1].type = 60;
            } else if (Game.Player.d === 1 && Game.Player.y < Game.Area.length) { //down
                Game.Area[Game.Player.x][Game.Player.y+1].type = 60;
            } else if (Game.Player.d === 2 && Game.Player.x > 0) { //left
                Game.Area[Game.Player.x-1][Game.Player.y].type = 60;
            } else if (Game.Player.d === 3 && Game.Player.x < Game.Area.length) { //right
                Game.Area[Game.Player.x+1][Game.Player.y].type = 60;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    Game.MoveZeds();

    for (var z = 0; z < Game.Zeds.length; z++) {
        if (Game.Player.x === Game.Zeds[z].x && Game.Player.y === Game.Zeds[z].y) {
            alert("Ouch!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You're dispatching "keypress" event while you're listening to "keydown". Could this be the issue?

Comment: I get the following error with either event: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<KeyboardEvent> has no method 'initKeyEvent'` - updated question : )

Comment: initKeyEvent is, I think, Firefox only. Check this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897333/firing-a-keyboard-event-on-chrome

Comment: Thanks zvona - most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe

```
evt.initKeyEvent();
```

should actually be

```
evt.initKeyboardEvent();
```

Comment: `initKeyboardEvent` is deprecated and its use is discouraged ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyboardEvent))

Comment: initKeyboardEvent is deprecated

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro What should we be using instead?