# Trigger keypress on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, jquery-events

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    // +
    if (event.which == 43) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="+" name="plus">
```

How can I trigger the keypress method with <kbd>+</kbd> when clicking the button?

```
$('input[name="plus"]').click(function(){
    // ??? How to go further ???
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 43; // # Some key code value
$(document).trigger(e);
```

Src: [Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('keypress',function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 43 || e.which == 43) {
        var identifier = e.target.id;
        console.log(e.target.id);
        $('#' + identifier).click();
    }
});
```

Comment: I need it the other way round: When I click the button a keypress should be virtually triggered.