# Is it possible to simulate a Ctrl+F key combination using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a page with a lot of information in it, and it would be nice if the user clicked on a link and the the browser search bar popped out as it would if they pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. I could query the database, since the information cames from there, but I don't want to reload the page on link click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Browser Search (Ctrl+F) through a button in website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080217/use-browser-search-ctrlf-through-a-button-in-website)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some browsers support [window.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.find)

Comment: That seems like the way to go. I just tested it in FF, Chrome and IE9.

Comment: @epascarello Suppose the text that I'm looking for is present at multiple places. Is there any way to get the count?

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is old but i think i solved this using jquery:

```
 //i am assuming you are searching through a table...
    //search input field listening for key pressed
    $('.search_input').keyup(function (e) {
        //listening if the key pressed is the enter button
        if (e.which === 13) {
            //inserting the value of textfield content, you can add if statement to check if the field is null or empty
            var search_param = $(this).val();
            //value of field stored into a variable
            $('tr').removeClass('item_found');
            //remove item_found class attributed to a td AND search all td to find the one that march the search parameter
            if ($('td:contains("' + search_param + '")').html() !== undefined) {
                //if there is any td that has that record... then check for the closest tr and add a class with item_found as value
                $('td:contains("' + search_param + '")').closest('tr').attr('class', 'item_found');
                //add some highlight to it.
                $('td:contains("' + search_param + '")').closest('tr').css({background:'yellow',color:'black'});
                //then scroll to the item
                $(window).scrollTop($('.item_found').first().offset().top);
            } else {
                //if item is not found display no result found
                alert("Sorry no result found")
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have found 2 bugs which I suggested as edit. Additionally, I have improved your code a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/1shqekzt/ : Making use of CSS,  don't allow empty search and made search case-insensitive. Idea for further imporvement: Add a submit button which can be used in addition to the Enter key.

Answer (score 2):

There are some plugins that let you do this, for example: https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys