# Use Browser Search (Ctrl+F) through a button in website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created a website and have added a button and lot of text. What I want is to use the browser search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), when I press the button which I added in website.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Probably it is impossible. But it should exist some js module that searches in the page.

Comment: unelss the browser provides an API for it (BOM - browser object model), you can't.

Answer (score 22):

It kind of works for FF. See [this page](http://webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=21406)

```
 <a href="#" onclick="find();">Find in This Page...</a>
```

Comment: You can also pass a string to it, `find('foobar')` will highlight the first occurrence of "foobar" in the document. Calling `find()` again will highlight the next occurrence.

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/client-object-property-method/window-find.php say list of supported browsers: Internet Explorer 7, Firefox 3.6, Google Chrome 7, Safari 5.0.1, Opera 10.

Comment: From my testing window.find() is supported in Chrome 37, and FF31, but not IE11. I'd be careful in terms of future support though: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672395

Comment: @Fabian - find() highlights the text in a webpage, but it does not scroll down to show the highlighted text (unlike the browser's search capability which scrolls down the page and show the highlighted text).

Answer (score 20):

update: from mark's comment:

> From my testing 
>   `window.find()`
>    is supported in Chrome 37, and FF31, but
>   not IE11

update:

for more information on this window.find go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find)

Comment: From my testing window.find() is supported in Chrome 37, and FF31, but not IE11.

Comment: thanks @Mark, I updated my answer by using your answer

Comment: hello, this worked for me too. I just additionally want that whenever i use find() again, it should search from the top on the page (and not after previously found literal).

Can you tell how to reset the find() function? or lead me to the documentation of it?

Comment: nevermind. got it :)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find

Answer (score 11):

No. In general, you cannot invoke browser controls from inside the webpage - security, sandboxing, and all that.

You need to make some sort of in-page search - if you're using a CMS, most of them have a simple search feature built-in.

If you want to do this in JavaScript, there are various scripts that *emulate* this in-page; randomly selected from my query "javascript find in page" is this one: http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/find.htm

Comment: I m creating a custom CMS, so I dont have any inbuilt search feature.. :( ny pointers?

Comment: Here's one: "Don't create your own custom CMS."

Comment: @T.W.R.Cole Or: "Dont use CMSs that you didn't create" ;)