# how to enable a hotkey with a button in html

Tags: javascript, html, search, shortcut, hotkeys

i am currently making a static webpage
this page will have a lot of text and i want the users to have the ability of searching exactly as they would do with the find feature of a browser(ctrl+f)
i found a couple of javascript files that could open a window and search but it's not what i am looking for, i want something that will search and highlight as fast and easy as browsers do so because i can't find something like this, i want to put just a button that by being clicked it will enable the find feature just as it would by pressing ctrl+f
it's hard i know but help me please

edit: i had find these too but you have to click to search

http://javascript.about.com/library/blufind.htm?

http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/find.htm

Comment: You haven't attempted anything yourself, you should program it first, if you hit a wall, come back here and we will help you.

Comment: Why can't you let the browser's Ctrl+F find-text functionality do the hard work for you? It's built for static text, after all.

Comment: @Mr.Alien i imagine that this needs javascript or even worse jquery but i don't have the ability to "program it myself" but i swear i searched how to do it in javascript

Comment: @michaelb958 this is my last option, but because my webspage aims to older audience i prefer to have a button, also a recent research shoed that only 10% of web users know about ctrl+f

Comment: @firstroad Why not a bit of text saying `Press Control+F to search for text`?

Comment: @michaelb958 cauze i told you i aim to an older audience
http://www.lolntroll.com/how-to-press-f5-key/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users have already pointed out, what you are trying to acheive will not work - at least not as expected and definitely not cross browser. It's also good to search before posting here. I found several links, however ultimately settled on a year old post on this website.

Ultimately, you cannot `sendkeys` at this level so either you need to create something similar to some of the links suggested by other users in the linked thread, or as @michaelb958 suggested, have the user manually hit Ctrl+F.

[Use Browser Search (Ctrl+F) through a button in website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080217/use-browser-search-ctrlf-through-a-button-in-website)

Comment: well i had already see this post on the link of the first answer but apart from not being cross-platform, it doesn't highlight the text while you search...

Comment: @firstroad I'm afraid this functionality doesn't exist in JS or HTML - having said that it may be theoretically possible to make something from scratch using jqeury and something like PHP but I really wouldn't recommend going down that almost endless path. With something like this link: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm it might be possible to add additional functions that temporarily change the CSS on found words but this would be something you would need to work on and then perhaps ask a new question once you hid a wall with it.

Comment: nice link, is there any way to make it work with the .keypress event of jquery so when you type in your keyboard, this searches?