# How to call browser "find" option with javascript like window.print?

Tags: javascript, button, browser, find

I want a button to initialize browser's find(control+F) feature with javascript. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Browser Search (Ctrl+F) through a button in website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080217/use-browser-search-ctrlf-through-a-button-in-website)

Comment: May be this could help: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/find_dia.htm