# How to automate keyboard events like "ctrl f" or "ctrl s" etc in javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, dom-events, casperjs

I want to automate keyboard events actions like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> down etc. using Javascript. How to do it? Please help.

Comment: Checkout this informative thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events

Comment: What do you _really_ want to do? If the idea is to force browser shortcuts, then -- thankfully -- you cannot do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery 
You can prevent event and call what you want , but you cant programmability call . This is "OnUserRequest" action , can be avoid only with user act .

Comment: @Arnauld , i want to invoke keyboard events like "ctrl f", on clicking "ctrl f" browser invokes find feature. I want to automate this process.

Comment: @lohith For the 'find' feature, you may be able to do it on some browsers: [Use Browser Search (Ctrl+F) through a button in website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080217/use-browser-search-ctrlf-through-a-button-in-website)

Comment: @Arnauld i am trying to automate using casperjs. will i be able to automate keyboard events programatically..? . I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: @NikolaLukic, can't i mimic user actions like ctrl a, ctrl s

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events

Comment: @Jakubee Why would you post the exact same link as in the very first comment.

Comment: @lohith Can you give an example website where we can test our implementation for this?

Comment: To clarify: you're expecting the web page itself to handle those shortcuts and not the usual browser stuff which PhantomJS wouldn't provide, right?