# Using browser search `Ctrl+F` through a button in user control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, keyboard-shortcuts

In my user control, I used webbrowser element as rich text editor. When pressed `Ctrl+F` a winform is shown and you can type searching. But every user may not know `Ctrl+F` to make search. Therefore I added an icon for searching to toolStrip menu. But I don't know what I code in the `SearchButton_Click` event to show search form as if clicked `Ctrl+F`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/hh801237(v%3Dvs.85)) to the hosted web control using the [IOleCommandTarget](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683797.aspx). It's supposed to be equivalent to [HtmlDocument.ExecCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.execcommand.aspx) method but for some reason, some commands don't work in the later.

The command you're after is [IDM_FIND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769909.aspx).

Here is some C# code to run it:

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dynamic ax = webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;

    // IHtmlDocument2 also implements IOleCommandTarget
    var qi = (IOleCommandTarget)ax.Document;

    // MSHTML commands group
    var CGID_MSHTML = new Guid("de4ba900-59ca-11cf-9592-444553540000");
    const int IDM_FIND = 67;
    qi.Exec(CGID_MSHTML, IDM_FIND, 0, null, null);
}

[Guid("b722bccb-4e68-101b-a2bc-00aa00404770"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleCommandTarget
{
    void NotDefinedHere(); // don't remove this

    [PreserveSig]
    int Exec([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid pguidCmdGroup, int nCmdID, int nCmdexecopt, object pvaIn, [In, Out] object pvaOut);
}
```

Comment: Hohayda... Thank you very much for the marvelous answer. This was an inextricable problem for me.

Comment: webbrowser1 is giving error (the name does not exist). I am using ASP.net and C#

Comment: @shomaail - please ask another question, it sounds like a compilation problem.

Comment: @simon  I found my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080217/use-browser-search-ctrlf-through-a-button-in-website

Answer (score 3):

As another simple option, you can simply send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to the `WebBrowser`:

```
private void findToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Focus();
    SendKeys.Send("^f");
}
```

Comment: Practice makes perfect, don't worry :)

Comment: webbrowser1 is giving error (the name does not exist). I am using ASP.net and C#

Comment: @shomaail It's a Windows Forms question, and `webBrowser1` points to an instance of `WebBrowser` control which you have dropped on the form. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET.