# Can I programmatically open the browser's native search dialog by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to programmatically open the web browser's native search dialogue from inside a web page?

And more over, if it's possible, can I programmatically perform a search inside of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Browser Search (Ctrl+F) through a button in website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080217/use-browser-search-ctrlf-through-a-button-in-website)

Comment: @epascarello, no, the `window.find()` API is a different thing. I'm asking about the native search bar that shows when you manually click Ctrl + F

Comment: I was not referring to window.find, I was just trying to be clear what you want. Native Search to me is when you "COMMAND + OPTION + F" and use the browser search.  Not the built in Find Dialog (COMMAND + F).

Comment: And this is been asked many times on stackoverflow and the answer is. There is not really a way to trigger it. The method has a parameter to show the dialog, but no browsers seem to really support it.

Answer (score 7):

There is [no way to open browser's utilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8080262/14386000) like find, extensions, settings, etc using javascript. However, you can create your own search with the prompt window:

```js
const searchBtn = document.getElementById("searchBtn");
const searchElement = document.querySelector("#text"); // Any element you want to search
const backup = searchElement.innerHTML;

searchBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  searchElement.innerHTML = backup;

  const search = prompt("Search");
  const text = searchElement.innerHTML.split(" ");

  if (search != null) {
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      let index = text[i];
      let splitIndex = index.split("");
      if (index.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
        for (let si = 0; si < index.length; si++) {
          if (search.toLowerCase().includes(index[si].toLowerCase())) {
            splitIndex[si] = `<mark>${index[si]}</mark>`;
            text[i] = splitIndex.join("");
          }
        }
      }
    }
    searchElement.innerHTML = text.join(" ");
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Search Menu</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="text">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
    <button id="searchBtn">Search</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also use `window.find()` to find a string in your page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Search Menu</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="text">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
    <button id="searchBtn">Search</button>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    const searchBtn = document.getElementById("searchBtn");

    searchBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
      const search = prompt("Search");
      const searchResult = window.find(search);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. It doesn't seem to work though: try "searchResult" and it will say "No results found". Also, is there a way to make the search results to be highighted exactly like the native search (e.g. yellow highlight in Chrome)?

Comment: @brillout I edited the answer. Check the new code.

Answer (score 3):

if you mean the browser search inside the page that's triggered using `command` + `f` or `ctrl` + `f` depending on your OS

you can use the `window.find()` method and here is a [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find) for it,

otherwise, if you mean the search bar which contains the URL of the website you can access its value by using `window.location.href` which will present the current URL

and if you want to do some search you can easily change it to anything just by typing

```
window.location.href = your_value;
```

Comment: In the comments above the OP already said this wasn't what they're looking for.

Comment: Bounty author here: I'm aware of `window.find()` but what I want (and OP as well) is to trigger the browser search dialog via JavaScript.

Comment: @brillout it's not clear to me that the Google/web search dialog is what the OP is speaking of.  Per one of the OP's comment on the question: "I'm asking about the native search bar that shows when you manually click Ctrl + F"