# Open the browser's find-in-page dialog

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to find how to open this default browser dialog programatically:

[image]

I tried `window.find();`, but that doesn't seem to work as I need to input text.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Browser Search (Ctrl+F) through a button in website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080217/use-browser-search-ctrlf-through-a-button-in-website), or [Can I programmatically open the browser's native search dialogue by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52835530/can-i-programmatically-open-the-browsers-native-search-dialogue-by-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

`window.find` is the closest one can get to this sort of behavior natively. Websites generally cannot control standard browser behavior, as it would pose a security risk. To emulate similar functionality and appearance, one can use CSS to style elements to look like the dialog and use JavaScript to implement the string finding.