# Is it possible to trigger a key event on the DOM Window with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, keyevent

is it possible to trigger a key event on the DOMWindow or DOMDocument in javascript? Basically I am creating an browser extension to interact with a website and they have shortcut Key Events (similar to GMail) on performing specific actions. I have found other postings on how to properly trigger key events ([Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery))  but they don't seem to work when sending the key events to the document/window.

So far I have tried:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
evt.initKeyboardEvent("keydown", true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 0, "o".charCodeAt(0))
window.document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

and a jQuery implementation:

```
$(document).trigger({ type: 'keydown', which: "0".charCodeAt(0) });
```

I also tried doing "keydown", "keypress" and "keyup" in succession but that did not work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you can pass extra arguments when using `trigger()` but I'm not sure you can overwrite properties of the `event` object. You can pass data like this though:

```
$(document).on('keydown keyup keypress', function (event, characterCode) {
    if (typeof(characterCode) == 'undefined') {
        characterCode = -1;
    }
    console.log('type = ' + event.type);
    console.log('characterCode = ' + characterCode);
});
```

And this would be the `trigger()` code:

```
$(document).trigger('keydown', [ "0".charCodeAt(0) ]);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A7cEE/ (watch your console for the logs)

The code from the stackoverflow answer you provided seems to work fine:

To Capture:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (event) {
    console.log('type = ' + event.type);
    console.log('keyCode = ' + event.keyCode);
});
```

To Trigger:

```
var e = jQuery.Event('keydown');
e.keyCode = "0".charCodeAt(0);
$(document).trigger(e);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A7cEE/1/

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same as `.bind()` in this case.

Comment: Hmm, you are right it does appear to be working with standard JS but unfortunately I am trying to run the JS in an extension (Chrome, Safari and FF) and for some reason the Key Events are being blocked. I have them running in the "content" scripts. I guess there is something in the extension API that blocks them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
evt.initKeyEvent ("keydown", true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 0, "o".charCodeAt(0))
window.document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

syntax:

```
event.initKeyEvent (type, bubbles, cancelable, viewArg, 
                    ctrlKeyArg, altKeyArg, shiftKeyArg, metaKeyArg, 
                    keyCodeArg, charCodeArg)
```

Use "initKeyEvent" instead of "initKeyboardEvent".

Answer (score 0):

```
//::jQuery::
//press "L" or "l" to open Bootstrap Login Modal Form
$(document).keypress(function(evt){
  if (evt.charCode === 108 || evt.charCode == 76) {
    $('#login-modal')
      .modal('bs.modal.shown');
  }
});
```

Good Luck.