# Is there any way to manually invoke "Enter key" event on a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to manually invoke <kbd>enter</kbd> key press event on textbox through JS or jQuery.

I don't want to capture that event. I just want to invoke <kbd>enter</kbd> key press event.

Comment: Do you want to submit a form?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Should that event trigger the existing key handler bound to the textbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can trigger it like:

```
// dummy event listener
$("input").keydown(function() { return true; });

var keyEvent = jQuery.Event("keydown");
keyEvent.keyCode = 13;
$("input").trigger(keyEvent);
```

See this post too: [Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

Comment: Not sure about that. I don't think it will! To counter this you can add a dummy 'listener' which does nothing and returns true. I've added a dummy listener in my answer.

Comment: LOL @ linking to the same post! Same thing this guy did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8608515/398242

Comment: Ahh! My mistake :) I've edited the post with the new link.. :)

Comment: This might just work. I believe jQuery will just add an additional event handler. So tacking this on at the end should still work even if there already is an event listener assigned.

Comment: This is really awesome.... Just had to change from "keyEvent.which" to "keyEvent.keyCode". keyCode works with IE. @techfoobar - I will mark this answer as accepted. But can you please put EDIT in your answer for "keyCode"? Thanks

Comment: `keyEvent.keyCode` don't work in my situation instead I use `keyEvent.which` that is work. source : http://stackoverflow.com/a/832121/1033510

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the event with jQuery:

```
$(document).trigger('keypress');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for synthetic events. It's quite complicated. The following library takes care of it for you... http://jupiterjs.com/news/syn-a-standalone-synthetic-event-library

Here's example code using their lib

```
Syn.click( {},'hello' )
   .type( 'Hello World' )
   .delay()         //waits 600ms seconds by default
   .drag( $('#trash') , function() {
     ok( $('#hello').length == 0, "removed hello" )
   });
```