# javascript onclick trigger key click (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

How can I activate a "left" or "right" keyboard arrow push on click of a div.

So for example

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    keyCode(37);
});
```

(I know that `37` is left)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would go like

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    $( document.body ).trigger({
        type: 'keypress',
        which: 37,
        keyCode: 37
    });
});
```

You can of course replace `document.body` with any other node that has a `keypress` or `keydown` event bound to it.

Reference: [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 2):

From [Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery):

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 37; // # Some key code value
$("div").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure, but can you try this.

```
$('.item').click(function(){ 
      $('body').trigger("keypress", [{ 
        preventDefault:function(){}, 
        keyCode:13 
     }]); 
});
```