# How to generate a 'enter' event?

Tags: jquery

it is possible to generate a click event like this.

```
$("#elementId").trigger("click");
```

but I am confused how we can generate an 'enter' event similarly?
I searched through internet and one way I found was,

```
$("#elementId").trigger("keypress",[13]);
```

but this is not working for me? Is this is correct? or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "enter"? the enter key is pressed, or mouse entering the area?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery

Comment: i don't think its programatically possible to fire user-driven event like click itself, if so i could trigger the event to open ads on my site when a user visits a page similar to invoking [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) and pose a security risk

Comment: @jimpic, certainly it was enter key press, not mouse entering area.

Comment: @optimusprime619, thanks for good piece of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13; // # Some key code value for Enter
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
var e = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 13 });
$("#elementId").trigger(e);
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to trigger a Enter keypress event

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13; // # Enter key code value
$("#elementId").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is incorrect. if you need the keycode try:

```
$("#elementId").keypress(function(e) {
  if ( e.which == 13 ) {
     //do stuff here
   }    
});
```

if you just want an event once the element is focus, try the **[focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)** syntax.

```
$("#elementId").focus(function(){ ... });
```