# Why didn't a jQuery trigger send some keydown events to an input element?

Tags: jquery

I have tried the following in jQuery to trigger a keydown event into an input box:

http://jsfiddle.net/W5fNh/8/

and wonder why no `keydown` event with `A` and `Enter` was triggered.  If I do type it in and press Enter myself, the form does get submitted.

The code:

```
$(function () {

    $("#the-input").trigger("focus");

    $("#the-input").trigger(
        jQuery.Event('keydown', {
            keyCode: 65
    }));

    $("#the-input").trigger(
        jQuery.Event('keydown', {
            keyCode: 13
    }));

    $("#the-input").trigger(
        jQuery.Event('keydown', {
            which: 65
    }));

    $("#the-input").trigger(
        jQuery.Event('keydown', {
            which: 13
    }));

});
```

with html:

```
<form id="the-form" action="some.php" method="get">
    <input id="the-input" type="text" name="var">
</form>
```

Comment: `.trigger` only calls events that were bound via JavaScript.  It can't emulate events that are triggered naturally by the browser.  Check this updated demo (look in your console): http://jsfiddle.net/W5fNh/6/

Comment: @RocketHazmat I was under the impression  that `.trigger` only calls events that were bound via __jQuery__

Comment: @ZachL: I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Maybe this question will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery

Comment: @ZachL I have tried all those and they don't enter the character or press Enter

Comment: sry I don't have any experience with this stuff... but with the `trigger("focus")`, should you maybe just be using [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)?

Comment: `trigger("focus")` works, just as `trigger("submit")` (like `.submit()`)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like the answer is: jQuery's `trigger` can cause the event handlers to be called, but not to actually emulate a user typing things in, to appear on the browser.

That is, except for the `focus` or `blur`, which actually will show up in the browser.  So what will show and what will not, I wonder what it is for each event.

P.S. for example, if it is radio buttons, then in fact they get "clicked":  jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/awbus/2/