# Perform keystroke onload using jQuery

Tags: jquery, onload, keystroke

As opposed to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3368578/1), I DO want to print text in a text box on the loading of a page.

I don't know much about jQuery so I'm not even sure this is possible. I want to set focus on a field onload, and then perform a backspace keystroke in that field (not simulate it). This seems on track(https://stackoverflow.com/a/16122568/3748951), but I don't know how to trigger the event and assign the value to the textbox simply onload. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: So, on load, you want to focus and remove the last character then perform the event attache to that input?

Comment: I don't think it's even as complex as that. I just want to set focus on load, then perform a single backspace in the field I have set focus on, that's it.

Comment: When you are saying on load (based on your text at the top of the question), you mean on document ready, right?

Comment: @Mr.Two-Arms why do you want to do a back space? To trigger an event or just remove the last character of the input?

Comment: @MiguelRipoll, if those are equivalent, then yes. As I said, I don't know much about jQuery!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon to remove the last character.

Comment: @Mr.Two-Arms ready and load are not equivalent, but that's not your question here.

Comment: @Mr.Two-Arms on document ready waits until HTML is parsed and page will keep loading as always, on load wait until all scripts and styles are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's what you want, don't need trigger *simulate* a backspace :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Select your input here
    $('input').val(function(_, old){
        return old.slice(0, -1); //Remove the last character
    }).focus()
})
```

Comment: That's it. I was trying to do a backspace using Event but it wasn't working.

Comment: @MiguelRipoll Yeah, those are fakes events. It's like when you use `trigger('click')` on an `a`, it will not redirect to the `href`.

Comment: Thanks @Karl-AndréGagnon this was my first foray into the stackoverflow boards, what a helpful community of people :)

Comment: @Mr.Two-Arms Of course it is, but on the other hand, you may find it harsh if you ask bad question... Glad it help anyway!