# Click to behave like a Return

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm building a `form` and i'd like to make my `radio button` behave like i've pressed Enter

something like `onclick="keycode=13"`

any idea how to do ?

Comment: Do you want it to simply submit the form or do you need to trigger a key press?

Comment: when i click my radio button i'd like to make the script think i've pressed the enter key

Comment: And what *behaviour* should happen when you click the enter key?

Comment: if( keyCode === 13 ) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    self._nextQuestion();
   }

Comment: Okay. Then this has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122380/trigger-keypress-with-jquery

Answer (score 4):

If you wanna submit the form, you can just attach the click handler to submit the form.

```
<input type="radio" onclick="this.form.submit();" />
```

Or you an even trigger the enter key!

```
<input type="radio" onclick='e = jQuery.Event("keypress"); e.which = 13; e.keyCode = 13; this.trigger(e);' />
```

Comment: how would you do the second one without jquery ?

Comment: @JérémieZarca Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler you can submit a form using the following code:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add onkeypress on your form:

```
<form .. onkeypress="return myEvent(event)">
<input type="radio" id="myRadio">
```

Than add Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myEvent(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
    if (key === 13) {
      // enter down
      document.getElementById('myRadio').checked = true;
      return false; // prevent form post on enter
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

I think the code above should work, because I have very similar code to prevent form post on Enter press.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, however...

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type=radio onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">click</input>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

i managed to achieve this by adding the followind code to the script

```
document.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {

            ev.preventDefault();
            self._nextQuestion();
    } );
```