# How to trigger enter event with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following which works:

```
$('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {
        alert('code');
    }
});
```

But I want to trigger that same thing when the page loads, I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13; // Enter
$('textarea').trigger(e);
```

NOTE: I want to have the first snipped of code there, I DO NOT want to remove it.

Comment: You should be checking `e.which` in your handler instead of `e.keyCode`.

Comment: jbabey you seem to be right. Can you post is as the answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use "which" instead of keyCode. "Which" works in both scenario

```
$('textarea').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == '13') {
        alert('code');
    }
});
```

Comment: (e.keyCode || e.which) === 13

Comment: @karaxuna Modified the code.

Comment: +1 I think your answer is what he needs :)

Comment: @ChiragVidani somehow you have not modified the code

Comment: @karaxuna +1 for the right bit.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution for your problem http://jsfiddle.net/dima_k/zPv2a/

```
$('button').click(function(){
    debugger
    var e = $.Event("keypress");
    e.keyCode = 13; // # Some key code value
    $('#textbox').trigger(e);
});

 $('#textbox').keypress(function(e)
 {
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {
        alert('code');
    }
});
```

Comment: isn't this a copy/paste of the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery

Comment: Take a look on a question. I believe, he already found the solution you attached, but it didn't work for him. So I attached a jsFiddle with working solution just to show that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
var textarea = $('textarea').keypress(OnTextareaKeypress);
$(function(){
    OnTextareaKeypress.call(textarea[0], { e: { which: 13 } });
});

function OnTextareaKeypress(e) {
    if (e.which == '13') {
        alert('code');
    }
}
```