# How to fire keyboard event to enter text in textarea javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am interested in creating an automated script that enter a status which are shown in textbox before submitting. I wish I can enter the textbox using keyboard event because I think there are some bot detection which implement the keyboard event check so simply `textarea.value = "something"` would not work.

Here are my code :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="reply_message"></textarea>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      $('#reply_message').focus();
      var e = $.Event('keydown', {
        keyCode: 65
      });
      $('#reply_message').trigger(e);

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope to enter letter 'a' on it, but it simply wont work, can anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks

Comment: really not clear what higher level problem you are trying to solve. What do you mean by *"bot...keyboard event check"*?

Comment: You misunderstand what a keyevent is.  You cannot use it to create keystrokes, you use it to detect.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir do you know how to do that?

Comment: @charlietfl For example I will put in a hidden input field called 'checktextInput' and everytime a keyboard event fired on the textarea, the value of the input field will also change subsquently, then after I post the status change, in the backend I will check if the value is matched. Note that there are too many code in it so I didnt read and analyse the code, but simply .value = "mycontent" will certainly not work

Comment: @charlietfl Do you know how to do this? I am not sure which mechanism it used to protect against bot, the input is just my assumtion. There might be other measure, such as when user input there will be an ajax call to the server when keypress or keydown to check whether the user have entered exactly the same value. So the best bet is to simulate the entrance of the text to textarea like real human which is using keyboard event. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to simulate key press events programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programatically)

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678161/how-to-trigger-enter-event-with-jquery/ ?

Comment: @Our_Benefactors The question link you mentioned above explain how to 'listen' to an event, but not 'fire' an event

Comment: @dramasea read it again. It certainly has the answer for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors sorry for not reading the answer completely. I have change the key code from 13 to 65(which is keycode for 'a'). However I cant see the letter 'a' shown up in the input box

Answer (score -3):

Maybe try something like this:

```js
function onTestChange() {
    var key = window.event.keyCode;

    // If the user has pressed enter
    if (key === 13) {
        document.getElementById("txtArea").value = document.getElementById("txtArea").value + "\n*";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `window.event` isn't available in all browsers

Comment: as I mentioned above, simply assign .value will not work in this case, as there are measurement against bot

Comment: This is how i get the key: `var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);`