# Google Presentation: How to trigger next from console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-docs

I have presentations in Google Docs, and I'm to figure out how to trigger the next slide via JavaScript. I'm playing around with writing a little web server that runs on my local network that I can use to access via my phone, which would trigger key events in the presentation, serving as a hack for a presenter remote. I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish the same thing, but I'm trying to get this one to work.

I've tried triggering a click event at various places on the page, but I haven't been able to get the presentations to respond. I've tried it on the window object, document object, and any other hooks I could try. i.e.

```
$('.punch-viewer-right').click(); // The div with the button to advance slides
```

[I also tried this code to get it to change via keystroke:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery?rq=1)

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 37; // the left arrow
$("body").trigger(e); // I tried as many elements as I could grab
```

But nothing seemed to register. I pulled in jQuery, so it was available, but I can't get this one to work.

Any ideas on how I get this to change slides via JavaScript?

Comment: can you make an fiddle of this ,so i can check

Comment: i to hit  with same problem but not with google docs , but with an images slider

Comment: A fiddle won't work because it's a Google service. However, [here's a link to a public presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zTaunxbCW5jbw6hTa7OZcgqnzdq5gKD_NVMmwAE9QXU/edit#slide=id.g1059d87_0_0)

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a keydown event for the spacebar (in the developer console):

```
document.dispatchEvent(
    new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{ keyCode:32, which: 32 })
)
```