# automatically press keyboard keys with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Here is a `button` whenever it's clicked. Automatically keybord keys are pressed `ctrl+shift+p`.
This is actually window print shortcut key.How can I do that. Because when `window.print()` function is used in google chrome. chrome show chrome print dialog box. but I want window print dialog and this is the shortcut key of window print dialog.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the default behavior of chrome print box. May be you can refer this link for that

http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2012/09/13/disable-chrome-print-dialog-use-osx-instead/

This will serve well for you but If you are looking something to do it globally for all the users then you may have to go through some other option... Will try to find an alternate for that as well.

Hope this be of some help
Happy Learning