# Executing keyboard command via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute the command ctrl + 0 on page load. Here is what I have so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    press.ctrlKey = true;
    press.which = 48;
    trigger(press);
});
```

This is not firing ctrl+0 and is also breaking another div on the page.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery?

Comment: Yes, but what is the input here? $("input").trigger(press); I just want it to fire automatically not when a users effects an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(document).trigger(press)` which will track `keydowns` on the whole `document`.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 48 && e.ctrlKey)
    $("body").append("<p>ctrl+0 Detected!</p>");
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  e.keyCode = 48; // # Some key code value
  e.ctrlKey = true;
  $(document).trigger(e);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This appears to be working, however the browser is not receiving the command. Pressing ctrl+0 should set it's zoom to 100% and it's not happening.

Comment: Thats an altogether different thing, you can't interact with the Browsing Software.

Comment: Probably there is no good browser compatibility, but you have the css `zoom` property which allows you to do what you are looking for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/zoom

Answer (score 0):

You can not trigger ctrl+0 in brownser, its security question.
but you can get zoom ratio of brownser.

Device Pixel Aspect Ratio
http://tombigel.github.io/detect-zoom/

github of project
https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom

Maybe is useful in you project.

Comment: Can you show an example of using it to issue ctrl+0 to the browser after page loads?

Comment: I can't simulate this, but i can get zoom ratio of brownser, maybe help you.
http://tombigel.github.io/detect-zoom/