# Simulate keypress from inside of JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has not been answered anywhere!

Hey i searched a bit and found only answers that did not fit me needs.

I want to simulate a keypress from with plain code, without selecting a element for it.

a bit like:

```js
simulateKeyPress(13);
```

and NOT like:

```js
$('element').simulateKeyPress(13);
```

I hope you understand what i'm asking for :o

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events

Comment: You want to output the input value?

Comment: ![Screenshot](http://i.snag.gy/G20DO.jpg) You got me wrong, why should i have to use a element as selector, i want to do it without.

Comment: P.S. @Jai This is not a dupe.

Comment: @Bluscream why is this not a duplicate?

Comment: Please read it again carefully, i need a way without passing a selector

Comment: @Bluscream just make a function and call it afterwards the intended execution of specific line of code. And yes this is a dupe...;)