# Text-area's value's not being updated with .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Photos of Problem [Please refer to this if my below explanation is confusing)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6lf8.jpg

I'm attempting to get values (answers) from a page and inject those values (answers) into text-areas on the same page. So far this script is able to do exactly that, however even though the correct values (answers) are entered into the text-area, checking the answer results in the page telling me its incorrect.

However, if I type, let's say a 'space' in each text-area after all the correct values (answers) are injected and then re-check the answers the answer returns correct.

Additionally, physically clicking into the text-area and pressing enter results in it being incorrect, however clicking enter in the same text-area a second time then changes the answer to correct.

I'm not very experienced with jquery, or javascript in fact this is the first time I've used jquery. 
However, some possible problems that came to my mind were:

1. The page uses some other way other than html form-validation(?) to check values entered in the text-area
2. The text-area does not get updated until the user clicks in the text-area and types something into the box

   2a. I've attempted to use `.focus`, `.sendkeys` and keypress events to simulate the user typing in the box. (didn't work)

Eventually, I intend to make it so that it automatically submits all answers, which shouldn't be too difficult.

So I guess my main question is, how do I update the text-area's value even though the text-area's values have already been changed by

`$( txtArea ).eq(h).val(ansTrim);.`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse)
 {
  if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" )
  {
   //Amount of text-area elements on page (found by class)
   var n = $(
      '.ember-view.ember-text-area.question-answer-textarea.min-width-text-area'
           ).length; 
   for (var i = n; i >= 0; i--)
   //click "Show Answer" for the amount of text-area elements there are
   {
    //The page requires you click Show Answer twice to confirm that you
    //want to see the answer
    $( ".ember-view.question-answer-show-button" ).eq(i).click(); 
    $( ".ember-view.question-answer-show-button" ).eq(i).click();

    for (var h = 0; h <= n; h++)\
    {
     //save all elements with the class
     var txtArea = $(
            ".ember-view.ember-text-area.question-answer-textarea.min-width-text-area"
        ); 
      //after answer is revealed stores the answer's text in firstAnswer
      var firstAnswer = $( ".question-answer" ).eq(h).text(); 
      //Orange check button stored in submitBTN for later functionality
      var submitBTN = $(".ember-view.question-answer-check-button")
      //Originally I thought that the answers weren't going through because 
      //the string saved in firstAnswer had an additional space 
      //in front and on the end
      var ansTrim = $.trim(firstAnswer); 

      //store keypress event in var press
      var press = jQuery.Event("keypress"); 
      press.ctrlKey = false;
      press.which = 32;
      console.log(ansTrim);
      //Fill each text area with the respective answer 

      $( txtArea ).eq(h).val(ansTrim); 
      /*
        $(submitBTN).click(function() {
          $(txtArea).change();
         });
      */
      //Above is my attempt at updating the textboxes with the values
      //in them (didn't work)
      }
    }
   }
 }
);
```

Comment: Would you mind to add the relvant html snippet and remove the scrollbar -by reformating your code?

Comment: I'm new to posting on stack overflow, what way would you suggest I reformat it?

Comment: My guess is that the field validation is tied to typing rather than changing the value. Maybe try triggering a keypress of "space" while in the text field and see if it works correctly after that?

Comment: @tdesignmr not the guy who asked you to reformat, but you have many lines that are too many characters. Put the comment on the line above instead. Also, does the selector for n and txtArea really need so many classes? You only have to match enough that it's unique, not match the entire set of classes.

Comment: Would you mind suggesting a way I could go about doing this, I had the same idea however it didn't seem to work. I just started using jquery yesterday and don't know too much about JS.

Comment: @tdesignmr look at triggering keypresses with jquery. Here is one such question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery

Comment: I've tried triggering keypresses in the text boxes as well however it's possible that I'm placing it on the wrong line of code. And answering your previous question regarding the selector for n, I'm not really sure to be honest haha... I'm mostly self taught, and I got as far as I did looking at other people's problems on here and a tutorial on how to make extensions for chrome. It was my understanding that the class name was just really long, I didn't know it was multiple.

Comment: @tdesignmr See my edits