# jQuery keypress event trigger not working on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to simulate an enter keypress for an input on page load, however it doesn't appear to be working.  I only find success when I click in the input and press enter.  I expect to see the alert when the page loads.

If you change the order I have listed below, then it provides an alert, but the key that is pressed is undefined.

Any ideas where I am going wrong here?

See demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/3xTM2/1321/

HTML

```
<input id="test" type="text" />
```

Javascript

```
$('#test').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));    
$('#test').keypress(function(e) {
  alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question... See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/832121/2159528

Comment: You are triggering the event before defining it. Just change the order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

Comment: @Ibu if you change the order, then it provides an alert, but the key that is pressed is undefined.

Comment: Your fiddle is using jQuery 1.4.2 and documentation says: `As of jQuery 1.6, you can also pass an object to jQuery.Event() and its properties will be set on the newly created Event object.`

Comment: It works [`just fine`](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/9cc7x9pv/).

Comment: @MikeDeluca You can check my answer below with the change of order and the change in the upper case in `Code` instead of `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, just change the order and change `keycode` to `keyCode` as below.

*Note*: Please note the upper case in `Code` instead of lower case in `code`

```js
$('#test').keypress(function(e) {
  alert(e.keyCode);
});



$('#test').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keyCode: 13 }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reverse the order, and assign the data to the event object on your version of jQuery:

```
$('#test').keypress(function(e) {
  alert(e.keyCode);
});

var event = jQuery.Event('keypress');
event.keyCode = 13;
$('#test').trigger(event);
```