# How to simulate keypress in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that modifies the controls of the popular browser game, Agar.io. Quick summary, in the game SPACE performs the split action. I want to perform the same action but by pressing D instead of SPACE. The extension works fine. It detects that D has been pressed and the my split() function is called; I know this because the alert pops up but the actual game action doesn't perform. I've looked around and tried different ways but nothing is working. Below is my JS file.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', keydown);

function keydown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 68) { //key D
        split();
    }
}

function split() {
    $("body").trigger($.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 32}));
    $("body").trigger($.Event("keyup", { keyCode: 32}));
    alert("Did it work?");
}
```

Also tried this method with no success:

```
var space = jQuery.Event("keydown");
space.which = 32;
$("body").trigger(space);
```

As shown in this question [Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery

][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

Comment: @Dekel I've tried the method shown in the question you referenced. It didn't work which is why I posted a new question.

Comment: Try adding a `event.stopPropagation();` after your `split();`

Comment: stopPropagation(); didn't work but thanks.

Comment: I think you need to look into content scripts. Basically you want to simulate the press of the D key in the context of the page - which is `Agar.io`, not in the context of your extension.

Comment: I think you might be right, I'm new to extensions I see there are content scripts which is where I have the code placed now. And there are Event pages which based on it's function I don't think that's what I want. Or I don't know how to structure it. If you're knowledgeable about Chrome extensions can you suggest what I should research?

Comment: use true for [useCapture parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) of addEventListener: document.addEventListener("keydown", handler, true); and declare your content script to "run_at": "document_start", don't forget to reload the extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the suggestion. I followed your instructions. No luck. Also tried "run_at": "document_end" and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. The code itself is correct and functional but the problem lies in the way I set up my chrome extension. Applying the solution found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/4651794 I was able to get the code to run. Not sure if this question is has any merit staying up as I thought the problem was with the key commands.