# Simulate keypress on contenteditable element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, contenteditable, simulate

How to simulate keypress inside of a contenteditable div **Programatically**?

I want to remove characters programatically with a jQuery script without any human typing.

I would like to delete some characters from the end of the span tag with simulating a Backspace keypress inside of the contenteditable div.

```
<div class="editor" contenteditable="true">
    <span>This is a span!!</span>
</div>
```

So the result would be something like this:

```
This is a span
```

I wouldn't like to rewrite the text. I need to simulate backspace keypress. Tested with this code, but nothing happened.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // after the website loaded
    // I want to trigger a keypress (backspace key) 
    // inside of the contenteditable div Programatically
    $('.editor').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 8 }));
});
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand what behaviour you want to develop. Do you want to remove character by character when the user presses the key backspace with a span tag?

Comment: No, I want to remove characters Programatically with a jQuery script without any human typing.

Comment: What condition or event would initiate said function?

Comment: The page load event, after the website loaded.

Comment: I would go with `str.substring(0, str.length - 1)`. Otherwise, check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/832121/1151408)

Comment: @Yuri Thanks for your answer. I already tested the solution that you linked. The main problem is that the contenteditable div is not working that way. Is it even possible to trigger a contenteditable element?

Comment: I have checked the selected answer and seems it is working and showing output in the console, but there is no affect on the 'editor'
did you find an correct answer for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used some part of code that was mentioned in the comments: [SO answer - Yuri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery/832121#832121)

Here is the part that triggers the keydown event

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // after the website loaded

    // I want to trigger a keypress (backspace key)
    // inside of the contenteditable div Programatically
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 8; // backspace key
    $(".editor").trigger(e);
});
```

After that, I created a handler to *.editor* element

```
$(".editor").keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.originalEvent === undefined) {
      console.log('triggered programmatically');
   } else {
      console.log('triggered by the user');
   }

   console.log("Key pressed:" + e.which);

   if(e.which == 8) {
       // do your stuff
   }
});
```

I also, put a validator to check if the event was trigged by user or programmatically.