# JQuery Event is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

When I use the following "jquery.event" line:

```
var newevent= jQuery.Event("keypress").which(40).keycode(40);
```

...I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.Event(...).which is not a function
```

How can I prevent this error?

**Further clarification:**

When the two lines I use are:

```
  var newevent= jQuery.Event("keypress").which(40).keycode(40);
  $('#juris1 .selectpicker').trigger(newevent);
```

This code triggers the event (and opens a select box), but I get the error.

When I use the standard way from the API documentation, I no longer get an error, but the code does not trigger the keypress

```
var newevent = jQuery.Event("keypress", { keyCode: 40, which: 40 });
```

Comment: So use it the right way: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation... https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

```
var newevent = jQuery.Event( "keypress", { keyCode: 40 } );
```

Per this post [Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

```
var newevent = jQuery.Event("keypress");
newevent.keyCode = newevent.which = 40; // # Some key code value
$('#juris1 .selectpicker').trigger(newevent);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Error is gone, but now the keypress won't trigger (which would happen with the old code)