# how to press tab key automatically on web page load

Tags: javascript

what is it possible to press tab key every automatically every 5 second on web page load.

```
$('.tg').bind('keypress', function(event) {
  if(event.which === 38) {
    var nextItem = $(this).next('.tg');
    if( nextItem.size() === 0 ) {
      nextItem = $('.tg').eq(0);
    }
    nextItem.focus();
  }
});
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery