# jQuery `keypress` event not firing for a div

Tags: jquery, events, tampermonkey

I have searched a lot and saw plenty of answers but none solved my problem. I am making a TamperMonkey extension for a certain website. All I want to do is to have a behavior that literally presses a key for eg. 'A' then press 'BackSpace' to delete the value again.

First of all, I want to solve the problem of pressing any letter.

I don't want to use `$('.classDiv').append('A');` because it doesn't appear as if a keyboard button was pressed. So I have used all the codes in the references below even understanding the difference between codes:

- [Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)
- [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically/19883789#19883789)

Maybe the following will give us a hint, the div shows multiple event handlers using FireFox:

- click
- onBeforeInput
- onBlur
- onClick
- onCompositionStart
- onCompositionEnd
- onFocus
- onInput
- onKeyDown
- onKeyPress
- onPaste
- onSelect

Note: the div serves as text input.

Comment: With a `contenteditable` element you can simply focus it and do execCommand like document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').focus(); document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'a');

Comment: @wOxxOm hehe, it worked. I don't know about `execCommand` but it seems a form of command functions.

Comment: @wOxxOm so I now added the letter 'a'. Is there a similar way to delete this letter??

Comment: Similarly focus the element then getSelection().modify('extend', 'backward', 'character'); document.execCommand('delete')