# Is it possible when i click a link that it does the same action when you press a specific key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, keydown

I have a slider that when you press left or right key arrow, the carroussel moves to the prev or next image. 
Is it possible that if i click a div or a link or something it does the same as if i was pressing one of the arrow keys?

Thanks!

Comment: This should all be possible, but it greatly depends on how the slider is implemented. If you need specific help, please add more details to the question

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can perform the same action that are triggered by Keyboard Events with clicks on elements like div. I recommend the onclick function. Basically you add an eventlistener to the div and trigger a function that manipulates the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question. You can trigger the Keydown event on one element from another event. So if you click a div you can fire the keydown event of another element.

[Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If you made a slider before try to use owl
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/
it is easy to use and work with I use owl in my projects that needed a slider or carousel
because it takes a lot of time to make a flexible carousel