# Simulate ArrowDown in an input when I place the cursor over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, input

I'm here struggling to figure out how to implement and what methods to use Jquery for the following purpose.

Scenario:

The user places the mouse cursor over input and it must automatically simulate a keydown (KeyCode: 40) in that input. This event serves to automatically call up a list that is only triggered by this key. Whenever the user places the cursor on the input, he must automatically simulate a keydown. At the moment the user has to click arrowdown but I want this process to be automatic

```
$( "#input" ).click(function() {
    $("#input").trigger(jQuery.Event('ArrowDown', { keycode: 40 }));   
});
```

Thank you for your help. I'm out of ideas here :(

Comment: what kind of list, are you looking kind of select box feature ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function arrowDown(ev) {
  console.log(`Arrow down by ${ev.type}`);
}

$('input[name="foo"]').on({
  mouseenter: arrowDown,
  keydown(ev) { if (ev.key === "ArrowDown") arrowDown(ev); },
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="foo">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or using the Event directly:

```js
function arrowDown(ev) {
  if (ev.key === "ArrowDown") {
      console.log(`Arrow down by ${ev.type}`);
  }
}

$('input[name="foo"]').on({
  keydown: arrowDown,
  mouseenter(ev) {
    $(this).trigger( jQuery.Event({type: "keydown", key: "ArrowDown"}) )
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="foo">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it didn't work. First, activate the function when I do mouseover. I wanted it to be when the user places the cursor on the input. Therefore click. Then I'm not simulating the keydown :(. The function I added results in a certain part. When I click it, it activates but for some reason I can't simulate the ArrowDown